# How to execute Ant without buildfile

Tags: ant, junit

I'm working on a project to develop a custom Ant task.

As part of automated acceptance testing, I'd like to execute Ant from JUnit (the opposite of the usual desire) and pass it a string containing certain build XML to be tested via a command line param or stdin or pipe or something like that, rather than referring it to a buildfile on disk.

Is there any feasible way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you simply use ant directly for running acceptance tests? i.e. do you really need to add the JUnit layer to it?

Comment: Using JUnit to run Ant for testing does not present a problem for me. Tempfiles work fine.

My question stems from curiosity, not frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant expects a file as input. You can however use the **-f** parameter to specify a tempfile as input:

```
$ cat <<EOF > tmp1.xml
<project name="demo" default="hello">
<target name="hello">
<echo>hello world</echo>
</target>
</project>
EOF

$ ant -f tmp1.xml
```

Obviously from Junit you're more likely the write the XML from Java :-)

Comment: Thanks. The tempfile approach is my default solution, but I was wondering if there was some way to do it without a file.